# Sending an error message to an application

Tags: php, objective-c, pdo

I am working on my first ever `.php` application!  All I am doing is posting some data to a database: simple stuff.

Right now, everything works fine, I can send my data to the DB no problems.  However, I want to return an error message to my Objective-c application.  I have the `try` and `catch` statements to make sure I connect to the DB, and if there is an error I would like to communicate that back to my application.

Here is some of what I have so far:

```
        $dsn='mysql:dbname=******;host=******;';
        $user='******';
        $pass='******';

        try {

        /* obtain a database connection handle */
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

        } 
        catch (PDOException $exception) {
            echo("Failed to connect to the  database. Error: " . $exception->getMessage());
        }
```

Also, is it possible to set a limit for how long the PDO will attempt to connect to the database?

Right now when I purposely put in something invalid, it tries to connect for a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to do what I think you are, it doesn't work like that.

If you want to pass the error message to an Objective-C application, you will need to pipe, write contents to a file, or write the error to `STDERR` and capture it from the Objective-C application.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Calling a PHP script from an Objective-C script?

Comment: I have an objective-c program that sends a url with parameters to my .php script, the script then reads the parameters from the url and posts them to the database.  I think `STDERR` is what I was looking for.

Comment: @HelloWorld I would recommend that you communicate with your Objective-C application using XML, JSON or any other structured format.

Comment: I would agree with @Rafael, if you are communicating via HTTP, use JSON to communicate.

Comment: fyi, php has a `json_encode()` and `json_decode` method, which will translate JSON to and from arrays/objects

Answer (score 1):

According to the PDO documentation, you can pass an array of driver options to it:

```
PDO::__construct() ( string $dsn [, string $username [, string $password [, array $driver_options ]]] )
```

In this same page there is an example of some driver specific options, also i believe you can use the PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT and/or one of these:

http://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.constants.php